# Add a menu to a DNN 6 module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm developing a module for DNN 6.0. I need to add a menu to the module, each item in the menu will load a usercontrol into a placeholder.
I'm missing the menu stuff any1???
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module level menus are not supported by default in dotnetnuke module development.

There are many ways to implement it, which is similar to normal asp.net development.

You can use query string, you can use asp.net menu and handle it's click event and there is an endless list of ideas.

Please add some more specific requirements to get exact tip on how to handle that smartly in dotnetnuke.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
I ended using "asp:LinkButton". I had problem with the asp.net menu.
10x